# How do I configure git so that some code only is checked out for people with read access?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git repository, which is accessed by two sets of users:

- build team (read only access)
- dev  team (read/write access)

The dev team, for their debugging work, would like to use some code that they will share only with each other - and should not ever end up checked out by the build team.

Same is true for the build team.

I've looked at using private submodules - one private submodule storing all the code that's shared between the devs, and another that stores all of the code that's shared by the build team (which they only would see, and have read/write access to). Is there a way to make this configuration work (submodule configuration/dependencies usually get committed into git, i think)?

Is there an alternative solution, which will make the git repo work the way we're looking to make it work?

Comment: Why can't the build team check out the code?  So long as they can't push what is the problem?

Comment: Could you clarify what this "code they will share only with each other" is?  Perhaps there is an alternative solution you aren't thinking of.

Comment: for developers, these are configuration settings, early versions of various modules and nuget packages, and development environment specific build tools, and configuration settings. for the build team, some of the same stuff (but as related to production environments), as well as automated test tools, security checks, etc...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to proceed with this particular idea you can use submodules, but invert the dependency.  That is, you'll have the following repositories:

- Main codebase.  Devs read/write.  Build team read-only.
- Dev codebase.  Devs read/write.  Build team no access.  Has the main codebase as a submodule.
- Build codebase.  Devs no access.  Build team read/write.  Has the main codebase as a submodule.

The downside is that if the build team needs to pull in new changes from the main codebase and that's it, they'll have to make a commit in their codebase to update the submodule.

It's also important to note that the dev codebase can't have its own customizations of files in the main codebase.  The main codebase will be a directory within the dev codebase but changes inside that directory would be tracked by the main codebase, not the dev codebase.  All dev/build-specific stuff would have to be tracked outside of the main codebase directory.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider git namespaces (see `gitnamespaces(7)`) to have the objects of  both variants available/shared.

Take a peek at the tutorials on workflows, either the ones that come with git's tutorial or the one at [Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows), check out the [git book](http://git-scm.com/book), take a look at [git in the trenches](http://cbx33.github.io/gitt). Comming up with the "right" workflow isn't trivial, `git` works *very* different from what one is accustomed with centralized SCM. In particular, as repositories are rather lightweight, you can have an "official" one and a "development" version (and each developer in turn pulls from both to their own copies as needed), and somebody doing the intergration of development branches that are OK into the official one. You might even consider (semi)automated code review tools, like [gerrit](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit) (but be advised that at least Fedora doesn't ship it due to multiple packaging issues).

Google is your friend, `git` is wildly popular.